# Anbox on 19.10 - claims kernel modules are missing

Tags: anbox

I've installed anbox from the default repositories.

The `ashmem` and `binder` modules are loaded:

```
$ lsmod | grep _linux
binder_linux          163840  0
ashmem_linux           20480  0
```

The `anbox-container-manager` system service is running:

```
$ systemctl status anbox-container-manager
● anbox-container-manager.service - Anbox Container Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/anbox-container-manager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-11-08 12:17:33 GMT; 7min ago
     Docs: man:anbox(1)
  Process: 1239 ExecStartPre=/sbin/modprobe ashmem_linux (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1250 ExecStartPre=/sbin/modprobe binder_linux (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1265 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/anbox/anbox-bridge.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1334 (anbox)
    Tasks: 9 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 11.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/anbox-container-manager.service
           └─1334 /usr/bin/anbox container-manager --daemon --privileged --data-path=/var/lib/anbox

Nov 08 12:17:33 frog systemd[1]: Starting Anbox Container Manager...
Nov 08 12:17:33 frog systemd[1]: Started Anbox Container Manager.
```

But when I try to start the session manager it claims the kernel modules are not installed:

```
$ anbox session-manager
[ 2019-11-08 12:25:39] [session_manager.cpp:130@operator()] Failed to start as either binder or ashmem kernel drivers are not loaded
```

Is this a known issue?

Comment: What happens on `sudo modprobe binder_linux`?

Comment: @Pilot6 - the modprobe appears to succeed, but the `anbox session-manager` result is still the same.

Comment: There'  no anbox-modules package in the Anbox PPA for Ubuntu 19.10: https://launchpad.net/~morphis/+archive/ubuntu/anbox-support/+packages and those are required to get it to work, even though Anbox is installed via snap.

Comment: The modules are now in the mainline kernel & the package is (should be) unnecessary.

Comment: After installing Anbox via Ubuntu Software on 19.10 today, I get the same error.

However in https://github.com/anbox/anbox/issues/1273 it is said that the issue should be fixed soon (in fact that already could have happened around these days).

So keeping fingers crossed ..

Comment: Can you verify if binder is loaded via `anbox system-info`?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1590708/511639  This resolved the issue for me on 20.04

Answer (score 2):

The kernel modules are there, but */dev/binder* isn't—because that's not the way the `binder_linux` module works, now. **morphis** however consider it not a bug, because they have a pull request to make anbox work with the current `binder_linux` module. As far as I can tell, you should be able to make it work with the "edge" channel of the snap. I.e.,

```
sudo snap install --devmode --edge anbox
```

but my experience with snaps is non-existent

Answer (score 1):

Same error here today, my system:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ntg-pc 5.3.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 18 05:37:46 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

One thing I've noticed is that although modprobe works ok,
only `/dev/ashmem` is created...

```
sudo modprobe ashmem_linux
$ sudo modprobe binder_linux
$ lsmod | grep -e ashmem_linux -e binder_linux
2:ashmem_linux           20480  0
3:binder_linux          163840  0
$ ls -alh /dev/binder /dev/ashmem
ls: cannot access '/dev/binder': No such file or directory
crw------- 1 root root 10, 53 Jan 21 19:10 /dev/ashmem
```