# Running Bionic Beaver and not able to get sudo modprobe binder_linux to load

Tags: 18.04, kernel, anbox

I am new to using Ubuntu, and I am trying to get Anbox to work. I followed the instructions for installing the `binder` and `ashmem` I am getting this:

```
ls -l /dev/{ashmem,binder}
ls: cannot access '/dev/binder': No such file or directory
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 10, 55 Apr 10 22:31 /dev/ashmem
```

I have ran both `sudo modprobe ashmem_linux` and `sudo modprobe binder_linux` and nothing. I have tried to research how to fix this issue and not finding anything to help.  I do not even know how to log my terminal info to even post what is wrong or what I am doing wrong.

To start, I did the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:morphis/anbox-support<br>
sudo apt update<br>
sudo apt install anbox-modules-dkms<br>
sudo modprobe ashmem_linux<br>
sudo modprobe binder_linux<br>
ls -l /dev/{ashmem,binder}<br>
ls: cannot access '/dev/binder': No such file or directory<br>
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 10, 55 Apr 10 22:31 /dev/ashmem
```

Answer (score 1):

See https://askubuntu.com/a/1206133/452115 : it seems this is normal, and `anbox` installation instructions on the website are outdated.

Specifically, `binder_linux` no longer creates a `/dev/binder` file. You need a recent (from the "snap" store) version of anbox to support that version of that module. From https://docs.anbox.io/userguide/install.html#install-the-anbox-snap :

```
snap install --devmode --beta anbox
```